# Wrap text around a dynamic sidebar of footnotes?

Tags: footnotes, sidenotes

I would like to display footnotes in a box, around which the main text will wrap.  I envision it functioning like the "wrapfigure" example at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/File:Latex_example_wrapfig.png, except with the footnote output in place of an image.  I would like the box to extend as far down the page as needed, even continuing on to further pages if that's what it takes to display the extensive notes.

I know just enough about footnotes and sidenotes to slightly customize their default implementations, but not enough to achieve the results I desire.  Is what I have in mind even possible?  Suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Footnotes and text wrapping are two or the most difficult things to customize in LaTeX.  It would be a whole lot easier to put footnotes into the marginpar area, or use paracol.

Comment: I had considered altering the margins to move memoir's "\sidefootnote" column into the normal text area, but manual margin adjustment eludes me.  Is there a dead-simple guide somewhere that shows the default margin values along with the commands to fiddle with each?

Comment: The geometry package  will adjust them, and the showframe option will display them.  Note that the bottom and right margins are just whatever is left over, no assigned length.  No text wrapping.